# RMSLE Evaluation in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for help because I've been stuck on this piece of code for a while.  I want to evaluate my regression model with RMLSE (Root Mean Squared Logarithmic Error), using this code:

```
rmlse <- function(model) { 
  y <- testset$Counts
  y.pred <- predict(model, testset)
  return(sqrt(1/nrow(y)*sum((log(y.pred +1)-log(testset$Counts +1))^2)))
}
```

where Counts is my dependent variable. However, this only produces NaNs. There are no NA's in the dataset. I can't seem to figure out where the mistakes are, if anyone can help out it would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's hard to say without a reproducible example. Can you share a snippet of your data set and the code that gets from those data to your NaN results?

Comment: Calculate all values outside the function and inspect each for errors.

Comment: It might be because you might have some values in your data that are less than -1. In this case `log(yourvalue+1)` results in `NaN`.

Comment: You might inspect `model` to check it contains something usable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in `nrow(y)` where `y <- testset$Counts` because `y` is a vector and `nrow(y)` should return `NULL`. See this example:

```
set.seed(10)
mydat<-data.frame(a=1:10, b = rnorm(10), c = rpois(10, 1))

y<-mydat$a
nrow(y)
NULL
```

If you change `nrow()` to `length()` you should be ok.

```
model<-lm(a~b+c, data = mydat[1:5,])
rmlse <- function(model) { 
  y <- mydat$a
  y.pred <- predict(model, mydat[6:10,])
  return(sqrt(1/length(y)*sum((log(y.pred +1)-log(mydat$a +1))^2)))
}

rmlse(model)
[1] 0.6234257
```

But do make sure that `y` and `y.pred` end up being the same length, otherwise it will throw an error, as I found out previously. I edited it to run correctly, but I thought I would let you know. If they are not the same length, you will get:

```
Warning message:
  In log(y.pred + 1) - log(mydat$a + 1) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue: How did I solve this error of NANa - and calculated RMSLE!

If entries contain negative values log() will create NANs. Now, If you can recheck your t.pred variable it should be having negative values. and hence it creates NANs.

Solution : to calculate RMSLE - convert entries into abs() : negatives values will transform to positive values.

predicted_value = abs(predicted_value)
actual_value =abs(actual_value)

SLE = (log(predicted_value + 1) - log(actual_value+ 1))^2

RMSLE = sqrt(mean(SLE))

Score = 1/(1+exp(RMSLE))

NOTE: Higher the Score - higher the performance.

Answer (score 0):

If predicted value is smaller than 0 then real value of logarithm doesent exist  so result is nan value.
You have to clip values below :
y_pred[y_pred<0]=0 for np.array
y_pred=tf.clip_by_value(y_pred,clip_value_min=0,clip_value_max=np.inf) for tensors

Comment: That looks like Python, but the question is about R